# Apache / PHP / Zend / PostGres site stopped working over the weekend

Tags: apache-2.2, php, zend-framework

We've inherited a website that runs on a Mac OSX server (10.5.8).  It has the following components:

- Apache 2.2.25
- PHP 5.3.27
- Zend Framework v2.3.0
- Connects to a PostGres database on another server

  - pdo_pgsql: PostGreSQL 9.2.4

Monday morning we got a call that the website isn't working.  The only thing displayed is the website background.  When I look in the source for the page I see that I have a start <body> tag and then the document stops.

There is no PHP logging on the site.  I made the following changes to the php.ini file:

- error_reporting = E_ALL (it was ~E_ALL)
- error_log = /path/to/php_error_log
- log_errors = On

I then restarted the Apache service.  Here's the errors I start to see in the log (it's actually bundled in with the Apache error_log):

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare printMediaIcons() (previously
>   declared in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/XXXXX/Website/module/Application/view/layout/header.phtml:20)
>   in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/XXXXX/Website/module/Application/view/layout/header.phtml
>   on line 39

I'm not a PHP guy but I understand the error message.  What I don't understand is how this could ever work.  I want to stress that we didn't change **anything** on this site.

In an effort to make some headway I edited the header.phtml file and took out the printMediaIcons function and any calls to it.  I then get another error, this time from the database:

> Tue Nov 03 13:09:05 2015] [error] [client 45.24.29.225] PHP Fatal
>   error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input
>   syntax for type boolean: ""' in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/XXXXX/Website/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php:438\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/XXXXX/Website/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php(438):
>   PDO->query('SELECT id, time...')\n#1
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/XXXXX/Website/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Adapter.php(190):
>   Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection->execute('SELECT id,
>   time...')\n#2
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/XXXXX/Website/module/Application/src/Application/Model/BaseModel.php(214):
>   Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter->query('SELECT id, time...', 'execute')\n#3
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/XXXXX/Website/module/Application/src/Application/Model/CalendarModel.php(71):
>   Application\Model\BaseModel->executeQuery('SELECT id, time...')\n#4
>   /Library/WebSe in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/XXXXX/Website/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php
>   on line 438

The SQL that it's objecting to is a simple statement to read the hours of operation for the business.  Here's the function that it's calling:

> public function getTodaysHours($timeTypeName)
>           {
>                   $timeTypeId = $this->getTimeTypeId($timeTypeName);
>
> ```
>             $variableHours = $this->getVariableHours($timeTypeId);
>
>             if($variableHours)
>                    return $this->getDisplayForTimes($variableHours['time_from'],
> ```
>
> $variableHours['time_to']);
>
> ```
>             $sql = sprintf("SELECT id, time_from, time_to, day_of_week
>                     FROM open_times
>                     WHERE (day_of_week = '%s' OR day_of_week = 'All')
>                       AND (is_dst = '%s' OR is_dst IS NULL)
>                       AND time_type_id = '%s' ORDER BY day_of_week DESC;",
>                       CalendarModel::getToday(), CalendarModel::getIsDst(), $timeTypeId);
>
>             $results = $this->executeQuery($sql);
>             $results = $results->toArray();
>             $results = current($results);
>
>             return $this->getDisplayForTimes($results['time_from'], $results['time_to']);
>     }
> ```

The site was working fine last week. I've examined conf files, ini files, error logs and this is all I'm able to turn up.  I have no idea what has changed/broken on the server.

Anyone have any ideas on how to start tackling this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!  The issue is with the **getTodaysHours** function.  Something in that query with regards to the is_dst is causing the error.  I returned a dummy value from that function and **POOF** the site is back up.

I still have *no* idea how the printMediaFunction was working before.  But I've wrapped it in a function_exists check and all is good.